# sem_post, signal handlers, and undefined behavior

Tags: c, signals, posix, semaphore, undefined-behavior

Does this use of *sem_post()* in a signal handler rely on undefined behavior?

```
/* 
 * excerpted from the 2017-09-15 Linux man page for sem_wait(3)
 * http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html
 */
...
sem_t sem;
...
static void
handler(int sig)
{
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "sem_post() from handler\n", 24);
    if (sem_post(&sem) == -1) {
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "sem_post() failed\n", 18);
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

The semaphore *sem* has static storage duration.  While the call to *sem_post*() is async-signal-safe, the [POSIX.1-2008 treatment of signal actions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03) seems to disallow referencing that semaphore itself:

> [T]he behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object other than *errno* with static storage duration other than by assigning a value to an object declared as **volatile sig_atomic_t**, or if the signal handler calls any function defined in this standard other than one of the [explicitly async-signal-safe functions].

Comment: If the purpose of the semaphore is to achieve thread-safety, then that's a special case. I would guess that the intention of the cited text is to avoid functions from accessing regular variables with static storage duration.

Comment: @Lundin, I agree with your read of the intention of the text, but I'm leery of inferring specific special cases here. Would your interpretation permit *any* static storage reference, so long as it is an argument to any one of the other 190 async-signal-safe functions? (*strchr*, *memcpy*, *rmdir*, *poll*, ...) That allows quite a bit. Do those variables become instantly unsafe if I refer to them in any other way after one of those special case references?

Comment: from `man 7 singal` *POSIX.1-2004 (also known as POSIX.1-2001 Technical Corrigendum 2) requires an implementation to guarantee that the following functions can be safely called inside a signal handler: [...] sem_post() [...]*

Comment: @EOF right — this concern is orthogonal.  It's not the safety of the function call, but the safety of how we get that function's arguments.  The spec says no static storage duration objects, then presents a raft of functions which have no practical utility without assuming static storage duration arguments.

Comment: @pilcrow Well, the C11 draft standard n1570 allows  accessing lock-free atomic objects in `5.1.2.3 Program execution` paragraph 5. So if `void *_Atomic` is lock-free, you can access a pointer the `sem_t` in the signal handler.

Comment: @EOF let’s stick to POSIX, thanks. In strict C I don’t think *sem_post* is safe.

Comment: @pilcrow Your statement makes no sense at all. C says that accessing the pointer is perfectly legal if it is lock-free atomic. This does not in any way *reduce* the safety of `sem_post`.

Comment: @EOF, I mean that the C standard itself permits only a handful of functions to be called in a signal handler.  So, from the perspective of the C standard, calling *sem_post* would itself be undefined behavior.  See § 7.14.11 ¶ 5 or SEI CERT's [SIG30-C](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers) treatment.

Comment: @pilcrow again, non-sequitur. C does not prohibit implementations to define behavior for implementation-defined behavior, unspecified behavior or undefined behavior. In fact, POSIX *always* extends from the C standard.

Comment: @EOF, why don’t we move this to chat or, better, why don’t you hazard an answer?

Comment: The use of sem_post is obviously allowed and intended as shown. No danger whatsoever that it would be undefined behavior :p. Note that the undefined behavior also talks about *assigning* a value; the argument is a constant (the address of a sem_t with static storage). Since sem_post is specifically listed as safe to be called from a signal handler you can be sure that internally it will only do things that are safe (most likely incrementing a lock-free atomic int). It is not needed to specify any internal types used by sem_t as that may vary from platform to platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, yes; there are situations where the behaviour is undefined.

I myself use this pattern quite a lot, and so does almost all signal-aware programs I've looked at. It is expected to work in practice, and be portable across systems, even if not dictated by any standard.

The POSIX.1 standard defines it as Undefined Behaviour, not because it expects programs to avoid such access, but because defining the safe access situations would be too complicated and possibly limit future implementations, for very little to no gain, as there is a well-known workaround for all such accesses: a dedicated thread catching the signals.

---

Added on 2018-06-21:

Let's first summarize the cases where the `sem_post(&sem)` access *is* valid in a signal handler (i.e., one can refer to objects with static storage duration, for example via any async signal safe functions), based on [POSIX.1-2018](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_03):

- When the process has only one thread, the signal handler is executed as a result of a thread in that same process calling `abort()`, `raise()`, `kill()`, `pthread_kill()`, or `sigqueue()`, and the signal is/was not blocked in the thread that was used to execute the handler.
- When the process has only one thread, the signal was blocked when it became pending, and it was delivered before the call that unblocked the signal returns.

This leaves out the most common cases: multithreaded processes, and also handlers for signals generated externally to the process (for example, SIGINT when the process runs in the foreground, and the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>; or SIGHUP when the session the process is running in is closed).

My understanding of the situation is that everybody expects that signal handlers that refer to objects with static storage duration via async-signal safe functions, will not trigger undefined behaviour on any sane POSIXy architectures; if one uses the multithread-safe (MT-safe) async-signal safe functions on objects with static storage duration, it will work exactly the same in a multithreaded process as it would in a single-threaded process; that signals triggered by `alarm()`, `setitimer()`, and `timer_settime()` behave the same as those triggered by `raise()` or `sigqueue()`; and that signals sent by other processes behave the same as those triggered by `raise()` or `sigqueue()` in the target process; with the only difference being some fields in the siginfo structure having different values.

There is even a small possibility that the wording should have *accesses* instead of *refers to*. That indeed would indeed allow passing the address of any object with static storage duration to async-signal safe functions like `sem_post()` even in multithreaded processes, like [Carlo Wood's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50009937/1475978) posits.

However, I believe that the reason for this wording is more subtle, and involves differences in hardware implementations regarding concurrent accesses and the contexts signal handlers are executed in: the behaviour in cases where some POSIX OSes might behave differently was too complicated to be standardized, so was simply left Undefined instead.

The rest of my answer attempts to describe those, for developers who do wish to produce reliable, robust programs that work on all POSIXy systems, and do not understand the subtleness of the current wording in the POSIX.1 spec.

---

The issue of exactly what objects a signal handler can access safely is complex. Rather than open up the whole can of worms, the POSIX standard drafters just punted it, and declared the behaviour undefined.

The hardest part to define would be the details related to concurrent access and trap representations. Not just by other threads in the same process, but also by the kernel. (Because we are considering only objects with static storage duration, we can avoid shared memory and all associated complexity there.) In particular, if an object has trap representations, and the object is modified non-atomically, it is possible that the intermediate stages of assignment cause a trap. And that trap itself may cause a signal to be raised, although there may be hardware limitations on some architectures.

So, anything related to trap representations is basically too complicated to resolve in the standard.

Okay, let's assume the standard would limit safe read access to objects with static storage duration, that are not being concurrently modified by the interrupted thread, any other thread in the process, nor the kernel; and write access to objects with static storage duration that are not being concurrently read or modified by the interrupted thread, any other thread in the process, nor the kernel. And that the object being accessed has no trap representations at all.

We still have a few hardware-specific signals to consider: `SIGSEGV`, `SIGBUS`, `SIGILL`, and `SIGFPE` at least. Unfortunately, some architectures may have additional signals not known at this time, so we'd need to define the type of signal affected: signals that are raised by the kernel when memory is accessed (`SIGFPE` only if the architecture raises it when loading the value, and not just when doing arithmetic etc. on such values). If the access to an object with static storage duration may raise one of these signals, then the access is not safe, as it can lead to a cascade of signal handlers. (Because standard POSIX signals are not queued, only the first signal of each kind gets to execute, and the process state can be lost, forcing the kernel to kill the process.)

From the POSIX C compiler point of view, the entire situation gets much more complicated if you consider a signal handler that obtains a pointer as payload (`si_value.sival_ptr` in the `siginfo_t`): does the access lead to Undefined Behaviour, depending on whether the target has static storage duration or not?

On all current POSIXy systems, accessing static storage duration objects through atomic built-ins, or when they are not being read/modified by any other threads or the kernel and the intermediate storage forms do not cause a signal to be raised, in a POSIX realtime signal handler, or in a POSIX signal handler that is not raised by memory access, is safe. This is likely, *but not guaranteed*, to be true in the future, too. And that is at the core of why the POSIX standard does not standardize it.

The cold fact is, there is a POSIX-compliant workaround for all the patterns requiring access to an object with static storage duration: a separate thread, dedicated to handling signals via `sigwaitinfo()`, with all those signals blocked in all other threads. That thread is not limited to using async-signal safe functions, nor do the other signal handler limitations apply to it. (If we consider the interaction between signal delivery and the code it interrupts, even with handlers defined with the `SA_RESTART` flag, one could argue that the thread-based approach is the better one of the two.)

Simply put: Because known workarounds exist, and defining the safe access cases would be too complicated and limit future implementations, the POSIX standard does not standardize this traditional use case at all. It is not because it is expected to not work -- quite the opposite; it works fine in all current POSIXy systems --, but because it is not worth the complexity and possible limitations to define the safe access cases (other than `errno` and `volatile sig_atomic_t`, which both require and have support from the POSIX C compilers).

Comment: "Some platforms provide the ability to mask signals while a signal handler is being processed. If a signal is masked while its own handler is processed, the handler is noninterruptible and need not be async-signal-safe. However, even when a signal is masked while its own handler is processed, the handler must still avoid invoking async-signal-safe unsafe functions because their execution may be (or have been) interrupted by another signal." https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/SIG00-C.+Mask+signals+handled+by+noninterruptible+signal+handlers

Comment: @RedArrow I think everyone understands the basics of signal handler masking (`sa_mask` and SA_NODEFER etc.). The question is about the safety of referencing variables, not about the safety of invoking this function or that.

Comment: Many platforms will have different kinds of signals that may get raised in different contexts.  In many systems, there will be some signals that are only raised in contexts where certain operations are safe, and others that may raised only in contexts where those same operations aren't safe.  Which operations are safe, when, should be specified in the system documentation that defines the circumstances when various signals will get raised.  If a system says a signal will only be raised in contexts where certain operations are safe, a *good-quality* implementation for that system...

Comment: ...will process those operations sensibly when invoked from that signal, even if there might be other signals where those operations would be unsafe.  Of course, a poor-quality implementation might behave in wacky fashion simply because the Standard says it can, without regard for whether sane behavior could have been supported just as easily.

Comment: @supercat: Fully agreed. I'm still not happy about my wording here (I'm not convinced that my wording conveys the correct concepts), so if you (or anyone else) do have any suggestions on making this better, all suggestions are very warmly welcome.  My purpose for this answer is to show that 1) even POSIX.1 leaves many important things undefined, 2) observations on why that is so, and why not worry about it overmuch, and 3) still produce robust, reliable, portable practical applications (by knowing some of the portability issues/details).

Comment: @NominalAnimal: I think what's best is to observe that the Standard often uses the term "Undefined Behavior" for situations which quality implementations should specify *as precisely as practical*, but where guaranteeing predictable behavior might sometimes be difficult or problematic.

Comment: @supercat: I think of UB as a mix of three cases: one is where the behaviour of existing implementations are deterministic, but differ for important reasons (that make unification of behaviour difficult or impossible); second is where the behaviour leads to unpredictable results or crashes on some implementations; and the third is where the standards folks simply could not untangle the behaviour due to inherent complexities of the situation (without bloating the standard with details). IMHO, the standard *describes* implementations, rather than guides their design. Wording this is very hard..

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Prior to the Standard, C could be described largely as "behave in a fashion analogous to the Ritchie's PDP-11 implementation, but with PDP-11 operations replaced with those of the target."  That worked really well for platforms similar to the PDP-11, but proved problematic in cases where it was unclear how certain PDP-11 operations should generalize to platforms that aren't analogous.  For example, on the 16-bit PDP-11, integer arithmetic would naturally behave as an algebraic ring with a modulus of 65536 (a power of two).  On a 32-bit two's-complement machine...

Comment: ...that math would also be performed with a power-of-two modulus (4294967296).  On a ones-complement machine that can efficiently perform operations in base 4294967295, but not in base 4294967296, however, it would be unclear what behavior would be analogous to the PDP-11: perform computations mod 4294967295 even though it's not a power of 2, do whatever it takes to perform computations mod 4294967296 even if it degrades performance by an order of magnitude, or do computations mod 2147483648 (cutting the useful range and degrading performance, but perhaps not as badly).

Comment: @NominalAnimal: The purpose of the Standard was never to fully describe the behavior of everything, but to focus on issues where it wasn't clear how implementations should be expected to behave [saying, e.g. that signed integer arithmetic need not behave in modular fashion, and that unsigned arithmetic must use a power-of-two modulus but need not support the full range of the underlying hardware types.  There are a significant number of cases where a behaviors obviously *should* be defined, but where the Standard doesn't do so--probably precisely *because* they're so obvious.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Perhaps what the Standard needs is not a bunch of complexity, but rather to explicitly state a simple principle: "Quality implementations should, when practical, make a bona fide effort to behave in a fashion their customers will find useful."  That would have been unjustifiably condescending in 1988, but some of today's compiler maintainers seem to take pride in their use of the Standard to justify behavior that their customers find unsatisfactory.

Comment: The proposed workaround (sigwaitinfo(), or some OS-specific constructs such as signalfd()) is preferable in most cases. I can think of one case though, where it doesn't work - getting the stack trace in a SIGPROF handler.

Comment: @UriSimchoni: Right; you'd want to stop the thread being profiled, for the duration of the stack snapshot at least. However, POSIX.1-2008+ does not define the context (the third parameter a SA_SIGINFO handler receives), so there is no way in POSIX+C to obtain the stack trace anyway! You can use SIGPROF and info->si_addr to do basic profiling, though (without stopping that thread). This is why I don't think that the SIGPROF case is an exception to my second-last paragraph. If you do think I'm wrong, do convince me: I am often wrong, and would prefer to be corrected when I am. :)

Answer (score 1):

This does *not* rely on undefined behavior. It is [explicitly stated](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_post.html) that the sem_post() function shall be async-signal-safe and may be invoked from a signal-catching function.

**No variable is accessed** (read nor written to) in the code`sem_post(&sem)`. The argument is a *constant* (some address).

Not related to the question, but note that besides accessing `volatile sig_atomic_t` it is also allowed to access lock-free atomic variables. I'm adding that because I suspect that internally a semaphore is using a lock-free atomic rather than a volatile sig_atomic_t. The latter is only "atomic" on a single thread / core; not thread-safe. E.g. there exist single assembly instructions that increment a non-atomic integral type, which therefore cannot be interrupted by a signal handler; but that still do the read-increment-write non-atomically with regard to other threads (no bus-locking). As a semaphore is intended to signal from thread A to thread B it is unlikely to have any use of the guarantees that a sig_atomic_t gives: it would still need a mutex for the access, which is not signal-safe.

Comment: I wish you were right, because it'd clarify things a lot. Unfortnately, POSIX.1-2017 does not say "access", it [says *"refers to"*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04).

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Some compilers devote a register to holding the base address for static objects. That register would hold that address at all times while running "normal" code, but might hold something else if a signal handler is invoked from certain interrupt contexts. The Standard would require that such a system handle objects of type sig_atomic_t in some other (likely more expensive) fashion than normal static objects. IMHO, the Standard should allow for weird implementations *but* also recognize that quality implementations should try to support features that some obscure systems can't.