# Are pthread condition signals the same or different from POSIX real-time signals?

Tags: c, pthreads, signals, posix

I'm learning about pthreads and signals in an OS class, and I had a question: is the underlying signalling mechanism of `pthread_cond_signal` just a standard POSIX real-time signal that has been fit to the task of waking waiting threads? Or is it some other mechanism that happens to use the same term to describe two different ideas?

If they are the same, I should be able to tell a thread to wake from `pthread_cond_wait` using `pthread_kill`, right? And could I somehow change a thread's signal mask so that it doesn't receive the signal from `pthread_cond_signal` when it should? I realize these are bad coding practice and hack-y sorts of things to try, but I just want to understand the underlying mechanics of the pthread wait/signal process.

I tried reading the algorithm [here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/nptl/pthread_cond_wait.c.html), but it went a bit over my head. My guess is that they are different, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: `pthread_cond_signal` does not stop or send a kill signal to a thread, it just wakes up a thread from `phread_cond_wait` . signal mask are only set to handle kill signals not a condition variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the term "signal" is used when speaking of both mechanisms, POSIX realtime signals and pthread condition variables are different.

POSIX or operating signals are "software interrupts" with [relatively rich semantics and history](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04).  They may be ignored ([SIG_IGN](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html)), delivered (*[sa_sigaction](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html)*), [accepted](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigwaitinfo.html), or [blocked](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_sigmask.html), except [when they can't be](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html).  They may have their [own stack](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaltstack.html) for user-defined disposal, though what one can safely do during disposal [is quite limited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48584862/132382).  They might take aim at [an individual thread](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_kill.html) or [at a whole process](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_28).  They interrupt [some functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html#tag_16_400_05), but [not others](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html#tag_16_418_05), sometimes at the end-user's discretion ([SA_RESTART](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html)).  Realtime extensions allow [signals to queue](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_314) and perhaps deliver a [word of data](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigqueue.html).  There's more.

By contrast, POSIX pthread condition variables are [synchronization mechanisms](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12) protecting some predicate.  Here, the "signal" is the user-initiated action of waking one thread waiting on the condition variable, if such a thread exists.

It's perhaps unfortunate that the same term is used in different senses when we talk about these mechanisms, but so it is.

Comment: You may add some more words about the asynchronous nature of signals to emphasize the difference?

Answer (score 0):

`pthread_kill` cannot wake a thread that is waiting on a condition variable, it kills that thread with swag and the rest of the code in that thread won't execute

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

pthread_cond_t conditionVar ;

int cond = 1;
int execWait = 1;

void * killSig( void * arg ) {
  puts("thread killSig");
  for ( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )
    printf("%d\n", i);

  pthread_kill(pthread_self(), 9); // control stops here, it kills a thread completely, the puts call will not print
  puts("this would not print");
}


void * condition( void * arg ) {
  puts("thread cond");
  execWait = 0;
  if ( cond == 1 ) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&conditionVar, &lock);
  }
  // if pthread_cond_signal(pthread_cond_t *_cond) is called,
  // control continues here
  for ( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ ) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
  }
  puts("this will print");
}

void * wake( void * arg ) {
  while ( execWait == 1 )
      ;
  cond = 0;
  pthread_cond_signal(&conditionVar);
}

int main() {

  pthread_t tid1;
  pthread_t tid2;

  pthread_t wakeThread;


  pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, killSig, NULL);
  pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, condition, NULL);

  pthread_create(&wakeThread, NULL, wake, NULL);

  pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
  pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
  pthread_join(wakeThread, NULL);

}
```

compile with

```
$ gcc testPthread.c -o testPthread -std=gnu11 -lpthread -g
```

Comment: "*it kills that thread*" and not just "*that thread*" but the whole process along with all its other threads as well.