# In C++17, is it undefined to protect data passed from a signal handler using lock-free atomics?

Tags: c++, signals, c++17

According to my reading of past questions, the standard allows accessing lock-free atomics in a signal handler, and any modification of "plain" objects becomes undefined. If that's so, is the following pattern, where the atomic variable is a memory barrier for non-atomic variables, undefined as well?

Pattern below is that of a single-producer-signle-consumer ring buffer. The signal is the producer and a thread is the consumer. Please disregard the inefficiency in the collecting thread that's spinning - didn't want to complicate an already complicated example.

AFAICT, this pattern is safe to use in signal handlers, because the atomic variables prevent any races, and I avoid memory allocations inside the signal handler. However it does modify non-atomic objects in a signal handler.

```
vector<vector<int>> ring;
atomic<int> push_idx;
atomic<int> pop_idx;

void init()
{
    ring.resize(8);
    for (auto &v : ring)
    {
        v.resize(10);
    }
}

int advance_idx(int i)
{
    return (i + 1) % 8;
}

int buf[5];

void sig_handler()
{
    int a = push_idx.load(memory_order_relaxed);
    int p = pop_idx.load(memory_order_acquire);
    if (advance_idx(a) == p)
    {
        return; // ring overflow
    }

    // fill up static-linkage data
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        buf[i] = i;
    }

    // copy some static-linkage data into buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ring[a][i] = buf[i];
    }
    ring[a].resize(5);
    push_idx.store(advance_idx(a), memory_order_release)
}

void collecting_thread()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        int p = pop_idx.load(memory_order_relaxed);
        int a = push_idx.load(memory_order_acquire);
        if (p == a)
        {
            continue; // nothing to do
        }

        auto &vec_to_process = ring[p];
        process_vec(std::move(vec_to_process); //may move-from
        vec_to_process.clear();
        vec_to_process.resize(10);
        pop_idx.store(advance_idx(p), memory_order_release);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `resize` provides strong exception guarantee it may be written in the manner that involves control entering `try`...`catch` block (even though reducing int vector size could be definitely implemented in non-throwing manner) so this code may have undefined behavior.I guess replacing `vector` with plain arrays would fix this.

Comment: @VTT isn't there a no-throw guarantee when the vector shrinks? (also a no-alloc guarantee b/c iterators remain valid)

Comment: No, there is no no-throw guarantee when the vector shrinks. I think `resize` call can be classified as "a call to the standard library function that is not explicitly identified as signal-safe"

Comment: Re: 'any modification of "plain" objects becomes undefined' -- modification of plain objects in a signal handler has **always** produced undefined behavior; it's not something new with atomics. Back in the olden days, non-local variables that could be modified in a signal handers had to have type `sig_atomic_t`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I suppose that settles the question then - I was kinda hoping that with the relaxation of restrictions on atomics in signals, the use of atomics as barriers is allowed. I now see that POSIX (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) also has this limitation, only allowing volatile sig_atomic_t and errno to be modified. Linux (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) isn't that restrictive - it just says the signal handler should be reentrant w/respect to global variables (which is kind of vague, but can be interpreted as "no data races").

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question based on the comments - it seems like it's undefined behavior, as it's always been.

As put in the answer to [sem_post, signal handlers, and undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584862/sem-post-signal-handlers-and-undefined-behavior) (which is about POSIX), it's undefined not because it contradicts the way signals, threads, atomics, or CPUs work, but because specifying the correct behavior is difficult with no significant gains.

In most cases the proper thing to do with signals is either to just set a flag in the signal handler, or "accept the signal" (sigwait() et. al). In my case this wouldn't work as I need to get the stack trace (SIGPROF handler) and deliver it to the application.